css doesn't work when DEBUG = False django
I'm making 404 page and i made DEBUG to False after that i fix my static
but my css doesn't get fix
my static file
static
  images[folder]
  template[folder]
      style.css

My _Layout <head>:
<head>
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'images/EasyBuyIcon.png' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'template/style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load bootstrap5 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}
</head>


If you have debug = False, make sure that STATIC_ROOT path is set and your static files are collected.
for example:
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles/'

python manage.py collectstatic

Here is more about static files in production

my css get fixed but i have another problem if i change my css file after 15minute it will load them and change styles

try using ctrl+F5 to reload cached css in your browser
